# Implementing a minmax heap using array

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, heap

So I am trying to implement minmax heap structure using array and my build function is not working like its supposed to.
its a binary heap so each node has 2 child nodes

The structure is identical to a binary heap, but the heap-order property is that for any node, X, at even depth, the element stored at X is smaller than the parent but larger than the grandparent (where this makes sense), and for any node X at odd depth, the element stored at X is larger than the parent but smaller than the grandparent Is it possible to do this using recursion? I run Heapify() everytime after inserting a element at the end for balancing the tree. so if my input is [7,4,2,9,6] outcome should be [2,9,4,7,6]

which implies that child of any node at index i is 2*i + 1

parent of any node at index i is at (i-1)/2

grandparent of any node i is at (i-3)/4

I have tried different approaches but could not get the expected results. I have googled the issue but still no success. maybe someone can take a look and help me out

getlevel function returns the height if tree at any given index i

index (vairable) represents the current index or number of elements in an array

My build heap function works perfect for a tree of level or height 3 after there are cases when heap is not following its heap property

```
void MinMaxHeap::Heapify(int ind) {
          if (ind !=NULL) {
                Heapify(getLeftSubTree(ind));
                Heapify(getRightSubTree(ind));

                if (getlevel(ind) % 2 == 0) {
                    if ((hasParent(ind) && items[ind] > getParent(ind)))
                        swap(ind, ((ind - 1) / 2));
                        
                    if (hasGrParent(ind) && (items[ind] < getGrParent(ind)))
                        swap(ind, (ind - 3) / 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((hasParent(ind) && items[ind] < getParent(ind)))
                        swap(ind, ((ind - 1) / 2));
                    
                    if (hasGrParent(ind) && (items[ind] > getGrParent(ind)))
                        swap(ind, (ind - 3) / 4);
                    
                }

        }
    
}

bool MinMaxHeap::hasParent(int ind) {
    int val = floor((ind - 1) / 2);
    if (items[val] != NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
int MinMaxHeap::getParent(int ind) {
    int val = floor((ind - 1) / 2);

    if (items[val] != NULL)
        return items[val];
    else
        return 0;

}
bool MinMaxHeap::hasGrParent(int ind) {
    if (getlevel(ind) < 2)
        return false;

    else if (items[(ind - 3) / 4] != NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
int MinMaxHeap::getGrParent(int ind) {
    if (getlevel(ind) < 2)
        return NULL;

    else if (items[(ind - 3) / 4] != NULL)
        return items[(ind - 3) / 4];
    else
        return NULL;

}
int MinMaxHeap::getLeftSubTree(int ind) {
      if ((2 * ind) + 1<=index)
         return ((2 * ind )+ 1);
      else
         return NULL;

 }

int MinMaxHeap::getRightSubTree(int ind) {
    if ((2 * ind) + 2<=index)
        return ((2 * ind) + 2);
    else
        return NULL;

}
```

Comment: Recommendation: add in what went wrong. You didn't provide a [mre], so we can't run the MRE and see that result ourselves. If we hack out our own MRE odds are good we'll either insert a different bug (and give useless answers based on that bug) or accidentally fix the bug (and give you no answer). And the last thing you want is answers that look like, "Duh. You left out the `main` function."

Comment: You really need to find hard the simplest way to have incorrect data. Add a validation function that you call after each _public_ operation to ensure that the structure is valid. Add code to dump data to a string or text file in an easy to read format. Once you have identified a problematic case, follow the code using a debugger and compare with expected result that you write on paper. Or find a correct implementation on the web.

Comment: Using `floor` on integer is useless. You should not use NULL macro for an integer. Also, your code won't properly works if 0 is valid data. I don't know how `getlevel` is implemented but I think it might cause a lot of useless code when you heapify large data while at each recursive step you know that next level will be a max if current level is a min and vice-versa.

Comment: *"but could not get the expected results"* -- All this tells us is that you have a problem. For all we know, you expected to get a heap (or print a heap, or traverse a heap, or...), but instead got a nuclear meltdown. Requests for debugging help should include what the expected results **are**, as well as what the **actual** results are.

Comment: What is `index`? What is `getlevel`? Please make your code compilable.

Answer (score 0):

following the advice from @Phil1970 in comments I started reducing number of elements in an array and backtracked recursion on each round which gave me the underlying solution. Looks like everytime I swap the values(based on conditions) an element I have to call the heapify func with index of grandparent of that particular node, earlier I would call the heapify func with index of root, so far this solution has been working good. Only thing now is time complexity which is really not a problem but I would like to know if there is a way to make this function's running time better

```
void MinMaxHeap::Heapify(int ind) {
if (ind !=NULL) {
            
            if (getlevel(ind) % 2 == 0) {
                bool swapped= false;
                if ((hasParent(ind) && items[ind] > getParent(ind)))
                {
                    swapped = true;
                    swap(ind, ((ind - 1) / 2));

                }
                if (hasGrParent(ind) && (items[ind] < getGrParent(ind)))
                {
                    swapped = true;

                    swap(ind, (ind - 3) / 4);
                }
                if (swapped)
                    Heapify((ind - 3) / 4);
            }
            else
            {
                bool swapped= false;
                if ((hasParent(ind) && items[ind] < getParent(ind))) {
                    swapped = true;

                    swap(ind, ((ind - 1) / 2));
                }
                if (hasGrParent(ind) && (items[ind] > getGrParent(ind)))
                {
                    swapped = true;
                    swap(ind, (ind - 3) / 4);
                }
                if (swapped)
                    Heapify((ind - 3) / 4);
            }
            Heapify(getLeftSubTree(ind));

            Heapify(getRightSubTree(ind));

    }
    
}
```